# React troubles with showing notification bar from another .js file

Tags: reactjs, notifications

I am currently in the process of learning React, and therefore I have began a new website project that I am currently working on. I have downloaded react-notifications (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications), and I got this to work on my register page by importing the necessary things, and also setting a NotificationContainer.

However, I am currently storing my register script in another .js file, and right now it doesn't do anything other than checking if the form that was submitted is not blank and that the passwords match each other. But, when I try to call the const that is showing the notification bar - nothing happens. It seems that I can only prompt the notification bar from events on the main page through either 'onClick', 'onSubmit' etc. Here is my code so far, and I was hoping that someone could tell me how I fix this, and also why it does/doesn't work this way. All of the form data is successfully being consoled out, but the notification bar doesn't show.

If I was to call the createNotification on my onSubmit, it works with no problems.

Register.js:

```
import { createNotification } from '../notifications/Notifications';
import { checkRegistration } from './RegisterFieldAuthentication';

    //Form submit
    <form onSubmit={this.performRegistrationCheck}>


    //PerformRegistrationCheck Function
    performRegistrationCheck = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            let submittedBrandname = e.target.elements.brand.value;
            let submittedEmail = e.target.elements.emailaddress.value;
            let submittedPassword = e.target.elements.firstpassword.value;
            let submittedRetypePassword = e.target.elements.secondpassword.value;
            let wasChecked = e.target.elements.accepted.checked;

    //CheckRegistration function that I have imported from Notifications.js
            checkRegistration(submittedBrandname, submittedEmail, submittedPassword, submittedRetypePassword, wasChecked);

        }
```

Notifcations.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';

export const createNotification = (type) => {
    return () => {
      switch (type) {
        case 'info':
          NotificationManager.info('Info message');
          break;
        case 'success':
          NotificationManager.success('Success message', 'Title here');
          break;
        case 'warning':
          NotificationManager.warning('Warning message', 'Close after 3000ms', 3000);
          break;
        case 'fill-all-fields-error':
          NotificationManager.error('Please fill in all the fields.', 'Error', 5000);
          break;
      }
    };

}
```

RegisterAuthentication:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';
import { createNotification } from '../notifications/Notifications';

export const checkRegistration = (brandName, emailAddress, password, retypePassword, checked) => {

    console.log(brandName);
    console.log(emailAddress);
    console.log(password);
    console.log(retypePassword);
    createNotification('fill-all-fields-error');

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `createNotification()` returns a function that can be called to create the `type` of notification used as its argument. What you would most likely want to do in your `RegisterAuthentication` file is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';
import { createNotification } from '../notifications/Notifications';

const createFillAllFieldsError = createNotification('fill-all-fields-error');

export const checkRegistration = (brandName, emailAddress, password, retypePassword, checked) => {

    console.log(brandName);
    console.log(emailAddress);
    console.log(password);
    console.log(retypePassword);

    createFillAllFieldsError();
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much, you saved me! +1!

Comment: But In this how to pass message dynamically via props